# Outlook RecurrencePattern.Exceptions.Count NOT updated after occurrence modified or deleted

Tags: outlook, add-in

I'm seeing a situation where the RecurrencePattern.Exceptions object, at least the Count property in Outlook 2010, is not always being updated after an occurrence of the recurring event is modified or deleted; sometimes it is, but more often it is not.  At this point I'm not sure if the RecurrencePattern.Exceptions.Count is the only property not being updated, or if it is the entire Exceptions collection.

When I restart Outlook and my add-in, all changes from previous sessions are reflected ... but subsequent changes only show up sometimes.

Is this a known bug in Outlook, and if so is it only in Outlook 2010?  Are there any workarounds?  This is for an add-in that does real-time updates to a SQL contact/calendar database.

Answer (score 1):

As Eugene mentioned, you need to completely dereference the appointment item. Even then, Outlook really likes to cache the last accessed appointment, and you need to open another appointment for Outlook to release the previous one.

Do you see the data updated on the low level (MAPI)? Using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author), select the appointment and click the IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon; take a look at the `AppointmentRecur` named property. Does OutlookSpy show the right exception count?

**UPDATE**:

if [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am also its author), you can try to use its [RDOAppointmentItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAppointmenItem.htm) object (the `Item` variable below can point to your appointment).
If you want to avoid stale data, replace `GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject` below with `GetMessageFromID`.

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Item = Session.GetMessageFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID)
  set RdoItem = Session.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(Item)
  set RecurPattern = RdoItem.GetRecurrencePattern
  MsgBox RecurPattern.Exceptions.Count
```

Comment: I've been using OutlookSpy to observe the items, and it was reporting them correctly.  

After seeing Eugene's reply on the MSDN forum, I went back, rechecked the code, and found that I was NOT releasing then nulling all of the references.  Once I did that, it appears to be working as I would expect.

Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Must be a reference hanging around someplace; it still is not updating, even after getting rid of every reference that I can find. Even getting the EntryID as a string, releasing the AppointmentItem before calling the method that does the processing, and getting a new reference in that method does not seem to be working.  Is there any way to find a "hidden" reference?

Comment: As I mentioned, it might be Outlook caching the last accessed appointment. If using Redemption is an option, you can try to use its RDOAppoinmtmentItem object.

Comment: hmmm, I'm finding that even OutlookSpy is NOT always reporting the right number of exceptions, although it does appear to have it down better than what I'm getting.  Dmitry, how do you make sure that you have released/nulled each reference?

Comment: When you click IMessage button, OutlookSpy reads the MAPIOBJECT property of the currently selected item. So if Outlook caches the item, you might get back stale data. Does it work better if you click IMAPIFolder button and double click on the appointment from the GetContentsTable tab? In this case Outlook Object Model is not used at all and IMessage is opened using IMsgStore::OpenEntry

Comment: Dmitry, is there a way to get to the REAL number of exceptions, and the list of exceptions?  Does Redemption provide this capability?

Comment: Yes, please see the updated answer above. To avoid stake Outlook date, replace GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject with GetMessageFromID.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what MSDN states:

When you work with recurring appointment items, you should release any prior references, obtain new references to the recurring appointment item before you access or modify the item, and release these references as soon as you are finished and have saved the changes. This practice applies to the recurring AppointmentItem object, and any Exception or RecurrencePattern object. To release a reference in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) or Visual Basic, set that existing object to Nothing. In C#, explicitly release the memory for that object.

Note that even after you release your reference and attempt to obtain a new reference, if there is still an active reference, held by another add-in or Outlook, to one of the above objects, your new reference will still point to an out-of-date copy of the object. Therefore, it is important that you release your references as soon as you are finished with the recurring appointment.

In C# use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it.  Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. See [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.