# How do I "keep" recurring AppointmentItem exceptions when modifying the .Parent?

Tags: vba, outlook

This is my first post!

I regularly receive appointments that are just for reference (not something I'm going to). They clutter my calendar hiding the actual appointments I need to participate in.

I wrote some code to change a recurring appointment to all day. It appends the start and end times to the subject so I can still reference it.

```
Public Sub MakeSeriesAllDay()

Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
Dim oApptParent As AppointmentItem

'Get the selected appointment
Set oAppt = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

'Get the selected appointment's parent (series)
Set oApptParent = oAppt.Parent

'Append the appointment time into the parent subject (series)
oApptParent.Subject = oApptParent.Subject & ", " & Format(oApptParent.Start, "h:mm AM/PM") & "-" & Format(oApptParent.End, "h:mm AM/PM")
oApptParent.Save

'Change the appointment to start at midnight and be all day
oApptParent.GetRecurrencePattern.StartTime = #12:00:00 AM#
oApptParent.GetRecurrencePattern.Duration = 1440
oApptParent.Save

Set oAppt = Nothing
Set oApptParent = Nothing

End Sub
```

It works great! The issue is, any exceptions are overwritten when modifying the AppointmentItem.Parent. How do I keep the exceptions? Or better yet, after changing the parent, how do I create new exceptions to reflect the old exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

When you work with recurring appointment items, you should release any prior references, obtain new references to the recurring appointment item before you access or modify the item, and release these references as soon as you are finished and have saved the changes.

This practice applies to the recurring AppointmentItem object, and any Exception or RecurrencePattern object. To release a reference in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) or Visual Basic, set that existing object to Nothing. In C#, explicitly release the memory for that object.

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Outlook RecurrencePattern.Exceptions.Count NOT updated after occurrence modified or deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298414/outlook-recurrencepattern-exceptions-count-not-updated-after-occurrence-modified)

[Outlook VSTO - Save AppointmentItem Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524084/outlook-vsto-save-appointmentitem-parent?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you Alina. My issue is not with the release or the lack of updating when I don't release. The issue is regarding overwriting the Exceptions because the Parent has been modified. For example, if I modify the StartTime of the AppointmentItem.Parent of an appointment with 20 recurrences and 2 exceptions, the modified appointment ends up with 20 recurrences at the new time and the exceptions no longer exist.  Can I prevent them from being overwritten or capture their info to recreate the exceptions after modifying the Parent?